# How to find the column of a specific value in a table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema, string-aggregation

I have a table with more than 10,000 records. When executing the query, I get an error message

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'balance' to data type int

The problem is I don't know which column has the value 'balance'.

And I have many, many columns. What can I do?

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(' SELECT * FROM [DM].[X]  WHERE ''balance'' IN (',
           STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME, ','), ')')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'DM' 
  AND table_name = 'X'
  AND DATA_TYPE IN ('int', 'nvarchar', 'varchar');
```

Then I'll get a column which I copy and paste it to SQL, then I run it
But it does not work.

Is there a simple way to detect the column of a single value?
If not, a more difficult way may also be okay.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to derive this info from the query that gives you the error. Don't you have the query text? Can you show us?

Comment: if you think about what your query is doing, you should be able to figure it out. the final query looks like: select * from x where 'balance' in (colvarchar, colnvarchar, colint)

Comment: and DATA_TYPE IN ('int','nvarchar','varchar'); -- you probably want to remove the 'int' part here

Comment: "But it does not work." Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this is query to find string value in all columns with sql dynamic query(use equal)

```
  DECLARE   @stringToFind VARCHAR(100)='balance',
   @schema sysname='DM', 
   @table sysname ='X'
   DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(max) = '' 
       
   SELECT @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = ''' + @stringToFind + ''' OR '
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
   AND TABLE_NAME = @table 
   AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')

   if(@sqlCommand<>'')
   BEGIN
     SET @sqlCommand= 'SELECT * FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] 
WHERE '+@sqlCommand

     SET @sqlCommand = left(@sqlCommand,len(@sqlCommand)-3)
   END

   
   EXEC (@sqlCommand)
   PRINT @sqlCommand
```